# Problemas na consulta MySQL

Tags: sql-select, mysql, group-by

Estou com dificuldade em realizar uma consulta entre 4 tabelas, sendo elas.
**Estados > Municípios > Óbitos > População**
A consulta está retornando o valor da população com um número maior do que o verdadeiro...Alguém consegue me ajudar a respeito dessa consulta?

```
select estados.nome, sum(obitos.quantidade) as Obitos,
        sum(populacao.quantidade) as Pupolação

    from estados
    inner join municipios on (estados.idEstado = municipios.idEstado)
    inner join obitos on (municipios.idMunicipio = obitos.idMunicipio)
    inner join populacao on (municipios.idMunicipio = populacao.idMunicipio)
    where obitos.data between '2008-01-01' and '2008-12-01'
    and populacao.data = '2008-01-01' 
    GROUP BY estados.nome;
```

Nessa consulta eu vou somar todas populações dos meus municípios e retornar o total por estados, juntamente com a quantidade de óbitos dos estados. 
Segue o modelo ER:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como estão os dados desse campo data na tabela ?

Comment: Está como date em todas as tabelas...Coloquei o modelo ER na pergunta...

Comment: até onde eu lembro vc nao pode fazer 2 SUMS cou COunts em tabelas diferentes na mesma  query vc vai ter q dar um union em duas querys diferentes e separadas.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido:

```
SELECT sum(populacao.quantidade),
    estados.nome, 
    (SELECT sum(internacao.quantidade)
  from estados as est
  inner join municipios as mun on (est.idEstado = mun.idEstado)
  inner join internacao on (mun.idMunicipio = internacao.idMunicipio)
  where internacao.data between '2008-01-01' and '2008-12-01'
  and est.nome = estados.nome
  GROUP BY est.nome) as internacao
from estados
inner join municipios on estados.idEstado = municipios.idEstado
inner join populacao on municipios.idMunicipio = populacao.idMunicipio
where populacao.quantidade  
and populacao.data = '2008-01-01' GROUP BY estados.nome;
```